# Can't find/run `configure` script on mac os 10.8

Tags: macos, terminal, script

I'm trying to install a program called [CSIM](http://www.lsm.tugraz.at/csim/index.html) (neural micro circuit simulator) and one of the steps is as follows:

> Step 2. Run:
>   `configure;` `make;` for Linux/Unix(/Mac OS)

But I can't run, not even find, the `configure` script.
I've already installed Xcode and command line tools.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 6):

That's the typical sequence of build steps for many cross-platform Open Source projects.

The `configure` command should be part of your downloaded package, so assuming your package is called `CsimOSS` you should

- open up your `Terminal`
- change to the `CsimOSS` folder (e.g. `cd` + dropping the folder into the Terminal window)
- enter `./configure`

The `./` in front of `configure` tells the shell to look for the command in the current directory (which is usually not in the standard search PATHs for security reasons).

Comment: I believe my package doesn't got `configure`... I'll try another download first.

Answer (score 1):

I found a great reference for this question that I used for compiling a retry program in MacOS Monterey 12.6.  It uses some homebrew formulae and is straightforward.  Just replace the open source reference and the name of the utility.  The crux of the issue is to use [autoreconf -- install](https://nanxiao.me/en/build-open-source-projects-without-configure-script/) to prepare the needed files for compiling.

```
# pull down open source code and enter folder
git clone https://github.com/minfrin/retry.git
cd retry/

# install needed packages using homebrew   
brew install gcc autoconf automake libtool make
# prepare the required starting files for compiling 
autoreconf --install
# now compile the program
./configure && make && make install

# test the program
retry --version
```